# Resizing with avconv causes pixellation in output

Tags: video-conversion, libav

I am trying to resize a video from `1920x1800` to `1280x720` for phone viewing.

This is the command I used:

```
avconv -i input.mkv \
-map 0:v -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 \ # map video, 2nd audio stream, and subtitles
-s 1280x720 \                    # resize
-c:a copy -c:s copy \            # copy audio and subtitles
output.mkv`
```

The output is indeed the correct resolution, but it suffers from artifacts.

Input:

[image: input]

Output:

[image: output]

Output detail:

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you don't specify a bitrate for the video it will use the default  256 kBit/s, which is low, hence the banding.

Comment: That's the reason! If you make this an answer I'll accept it as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't specify a bitrate for the video, it will choose the `mpeg4` video encoder for the MKV container. It uses a default of 200 kBit/s, which is low, hence the visual artifacts.

If you want to increase the quality, you have three options:

- Choose a higher bitrate (e.g. `-b:v 1000K`)
- Choose variable quality (e.g. `-q:v 1`). Lower means better. Good values are between 1 and 4.
- Choose a higher quality video codec, e.g. H.264 (`-c:v libx264`) and set the CRF for quality (e.g. `-crf 23`). Lower means better, and sane values are between 18 and 28.